# How to add custom layout in CardListView for gabrielemariotti cards

Tags: android, listview, cardslib

I am Creating a Application with cardlistview..
I implemented the cards list view using gabrielemariotti cards library
[gabrielemariotti cards](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)

I am able to achieve the cardlist view and by inflating the custom layout is also successfull. While i cannot set the values to textviews inside the custom layout texview as it is getting null values..

My Card list XML is:

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView
                android:id="@+id/myList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                card:list_card_layout_resourceID="@layout/news_card"/>
```

news_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_cardId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/card_thumbnail_layout"
    />
```

news_card_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="News"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myNews"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="news" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mydate"
        android:gravity="right"
        tools:text="date" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity code to create the cards":

```
 ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                // Create a Card
                Card card1 = new Card(this.getActivity(),R.layout.news_card_layout);
                CardHeader header1 = new CardHeader(this.getActivity());
                // Add Header to card
                header1.setTitle("hi");
                card1.addCardHeader(header1);
                CardThumbnail thumb = new CardThumbnail(this.getActivity());
                thumb.setUrlResource("https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-N8bz9q4Kz0I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAs/Icl2bQMyK7c/s265-c-k-no/photo.jpg");
                card1.addCardThumbnail(thumb);

                TextView newsdesc = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.myNews);
                newsdesc.setText("hello");
                /*TextView mydate = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.mydate);
                mydate.setText("2 Seconds ago");*/
                cards.add(card1);
                card1.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clickable card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), cards);

            CardListView listView = (CardListView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.myList);
            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer..
I Just created a custom card class

CustomCard Class:

```
public class CustomCard extends Card {

    protected TextView myDesc;
    protected TextView myDate;
    public String news;
    public String date;

    /**
     * Constructor with a custom inner layout
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomCard(Context context) {

        this(context, R.layout.news_card_layout);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @param innerLayout
     */
    public CustomCard(Context context, int innerLayout) {
        super(context, innerLayout);
        //init();
    }

    /**
     * Init
     */
    private void init(){

        //No Header

        //Set a OnClickListener listener
        setOnClickListener(new OnCardClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click Listener card=", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {

        //Retrieve elements
        myDesc = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.myNews);
        myDate = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.myDate);
        if (myDesc != null)
            myDesc.setText(news);
        if (myDate != null)
            myDate.setText(date);
    }

    public void setNews(String news) {
        this.news=news;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date=date;
    }
```

Activity Code:

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                // Create a Card
                CustomCard card1 = new CustomCard(this.getActivity(),R.layout.news_card_layout);
                CardHeader header1 = new CardHeader(this.getActivity());
                // Add Header to card
                header1.setTitle("hi");
                card1.addCardHeader(header1);
                CardThumbnail thumb = new CardThumbnail(this.getActivity());
                thumb.setUrlResource("https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-N8bz9q4Kz0I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAs/Icl2bQMyK7c/s265-c-k-no/photo.jpg");
                card1.addCardThumbnail(thumb);

               card1.setNews("test");
        card1.setDate("12/3/2017");
                cards.add(card1);
                card1.setOnClickListener(new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clickable card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), cards);

            CardListView listView = (CardListView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.myList);
            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
            }
```

-----IT SOLVES THE PROBLEM----